# Codeigniter: unable to display the uploaded image with spaces and capitalizing subsequent words

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

From my below code i am able to upload images with spaces and capitalizing subsequent words, but if i try to view such images into my view page then its not visible. I am getting error like `The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.`

I am displaying images like `<img   src="<?php echo base_url().'uploads/avatar/'.$avatar?>"/>`
So how can i fix this error, to allow  img tag to read image name with spaces and capitalizing subsequent words.

Or alternative solution, How how can i remove any spaces or  capitalizing subsequent words with the image name while uploading?

I am uploading file with the below code.

```
   function do_upload()
        { 
         $this->load->library('form_validation'); 

        if((isset($_FILES['userfile']['size'])) && ($_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0))
            {
                 $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<li  class="errorlist">', '</li>')->set_rules('userfile', 'New Image', 'trim|callback_valid_upload_userfile');   
            }    
      $uid=$this->session->userdata('userid');
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/avatar/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '5000'; 
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);  

 if ( $this->input->post('user_id') && $this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
 {  
         $avatar= $_FILES['userfile']['name'];  //getting the file name  
          $this->loginmodel->update_user_basic_info($uid); //update both 

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's pretty simple, use:

`$config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;`

So you have to take the filename from `$this->upload->data()` and **not** from `$_FILES` after  the upload process.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to generate friendly image filenames that will play nice with URLs...Perhaps you could [extend CodeIgniter's URL helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html) to contain a function called `slugify()`, for instance.

Create `MY_url_helper.php` in `application/helpers/` directory. The contents of this file:

```
<?php
function slugify($text){ 
  // replace non letter or digits by -
  $text = preg_replace('~[^\\pL\d]+~u', '-', $text);
  // trim
  $text = trim($text, '-');
  // transliterate
  $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
  // lowercase
  $text = strtolower($text);
  // remove unwanted characters
  $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $text);
  if (empty($text)) return "";
  return $text;
}
```

Next, [autoload](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/autoloader.html) the url helper by adding the entry in `config/autoload.php`... for example: `$autoload['helper'] = array('html', 'url', ...);`

Finally, use `slugify()`...

`$image1= slugify($_FILES['userfile']['name']);`

As for explaining how each step of slugify works, it's really embedded in the comments. It takes the input filename argument and preps it into a more URL friendly equivalent one operation at a time.

Comment: Can you please litle expand your answer with more detail ,  i am new in php,i could not understand straightforward answer

Comment: Never use user supplied image name to your program, May be they contain problematic and offensive word.So change them before uploading.Then above problem will be solved automatically.

Comment: @SusheelMishra I know that if i change its name, then my above probelm will solve. Can you post  an answer with code & litle explanation what you said in your sentences?

Comment: I have small doubt, so in my code where should replace this `$image1= slugify($_FILES['userfile']['name']);`

Comment: i updated, so now if i upload a new image say its name is `a bc.jpg` then i will get new name as something without space, right? , and Is the name name  will also save into my "upload/avatar/" folder?

Comment: that is correct. it will be converted to a-bc.jpg, which is valid.

Comment: @SusheelMishra's advice will also work, but image slugs are better for SEO.

Comment: Getting error:  if my image name is `a bc.jpg` then its saving into my upload folder as `a_bc.jpg` and in the db as `a-bc-jpg`  Why? Please help

Comment: fetch avatar name just before executing in query,Surely it will clear something.Debug around update_user_avatar function.