# file name changes when i upload i file using do_upload function

Tags: php

when i upload a file using do_upload() in code igniter, it uploads the file but it renames it with underscore(_) in the place of blank spaces.
file name to be uploaded: A B C.pdf
file that uploads: A_B_C.pdf

code in controller to upload file:

```
//$filefeild is the name of folder in which file is to be saved
public function upload_Files($filefeild)
    {
        //set preferences
        $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/bcc/'.$filefeild."/";
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'doc|docx|xml|pdf|image|excel|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size']    = 0;
        $config['filname'] = $filenamee = $_FILES[$filefeild]['name'];
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload($filefeild))
        {
            // case - failure
            $upload_error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        }
        else
        {
            // case - success
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
            $data['success_msg'] = '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your file <strong>' . $upload_data['file_name'] . '</strong> was successfully uploaded!</div>';
            $filname = $upload_data['file_name'];
            return $filenamee;
        }


    }
```

Comment: maybe a quick look at how the `codeigniter`'s function written would help you! https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/3b470a6934a030c4bc57ac4c070539b5dd3e13b9/system/libraries/Upload.php#L374

Answer (score 0):

IF you see codeigniter's function exist [here](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/3b470a6934a030c4bc57ac4c070539b5dd3e13b9/system/libraries/Upload.php#L374), you will find following code,

```
// Remove white spaces in the name
if ($this->remove_spaces === TRUE)
{
    $this->file_name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $this->file_name);
}
```

Which means codeigniter removes spaced and adds _ by default which can be changed by setting config variable. like `$config['remove_spaces'] = FALSE;`

Secondly if you want your file should be saved with underscors and you get actual name by which file is being saved then in your code you have to make a slight change as described below.
your current code

```
$config['filname'] = $filenamee = $_FILES[$filefeild]['name'];
```

Change it to

```
$config['filname'] = $_FILES[$filefeild]['name'];
```

and in success scenario get file name from `$this->upload->data()`

**Note:** you can find answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372816/codeigniter-unable-to-display-the-uploaded-image-with-spaces-and-capitalizing-s) aswell.